# how to set cursor position in cell of grouping grid of syncfusion?

Tags: c#, syncfusion

I am developing a windows application using syncfusion controls. I have a grid grouping grid and I want to set cursor position to the end of the text if user click any where in a cell. How i can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void grd_TableControlCurrentCellChanged(object sender, GridTableControlEventArgs e)
{
   GridDropDownGridListControlCellRenderer cr = 
      gcc.Renderer as GridDropDownGridListControlCellRenderer;
          if (cr != null)
          {
              cr.TextBox.SelectionStart = cr.TextBox.TextLength;
              cr.TextBox.SelectionLength = 0;
          }
}
```